# Using backstack and back button in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, back-stack

I'm using a viewpager to swipe between fragments and would like the back button to navigate to the previously viewed fragment rather than ending the activity. Sorry if this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712917/use-backstack-with-viewpager) however I didn't find the answer very helpful. Obviously onBackPressed needs to be overridden, but I don't know how to get and display the correct fragment. I assume that I should use the fragmentmanager's backstack, but `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` always returns 0. Do I need to manually add fragments to the backstack using `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()`? If so, where would I add this in my adapter?

Here is the code for my activity,

```
public class PagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ArrayList<Sale> sales;
MyAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent it = getIntent();
    this.sales = (ArrayList<Sale>) it.getExtras().get("sales");
    int position = it.getExtras().getInt("position");

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(position);

}

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sales.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        SalesThumbFragment frag = new SalesThumbFragment();
        return frag.newInstance(sales.get(position));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sales_controller, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  } else {

    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}


}
```

Answer (score 8):

**In new design support library, i use this** 
I have same issue and i follow this step

In the main activity where there are 3 fragment in viewpager i create stack 
and push and pop data.

```
//private Stack<Integer> stackkk;  ==> As i get edit suggestion 
private Stack<Integer> stackkk = new Stack<>(); // Edited 
private ViewPager mPager;
private int tabPosition = 0;



    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            if (stackkk.empty())
                stackkk.push(0);

            if (stackkk.contains(tabPosition)) {
                stackkk.remove(stackkk.indexOf(tabPosition));
                stackkk.push(tabPosition);
            } else {
                stackkk.push(tabPosition);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tabPositionUnselected = tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}
```

and in the onBackPressed in activity,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (stackkk.size() > 1) {
        stackkk.pop();
        mPager.setCurrentItem(stackkk.lastElement());
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Suggestion as i have change my code 

form 
private Stack<Integer> stackkk;

to
private Stack<Integer> stackkk = new Stack<>();

Created new object every time.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in Fragment Activity class. Don't forget to add return true;

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPageSelected - 1);
            return true;
        }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, this is how I solved it. I think you can adapt the code to your problem, if I understood what you problem is. I had a ViewPager with 6 fragments and wanted to keep track of the page history and to be able to use the back button to navigate backwards in the history. I create a `java.util.Stack<Integer>` object, add fragment numbers to it (except when you use the back button, see below), and override `onBackPressed()` to make it pop the last viewed fragment instead of using the back stack, when my history stack is not empty.

You want to avoid pushing elements on the Stack when you press the back button, otherwise you will get stuck between two fragments if you keep using the back button, instead of eventually exiting.

My code:

```
MyAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
Stack<Integer> pageHistory;
int currentPage;
boolean saveToHistory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

    pageHistory = new Stack<Integer>();
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            if(saveToHistory)
                pageHistory.push(Integer.valueOf(currentPage));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
    saveToHistory = true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(pageHistory.empty())
        super.onBackPressed();
    else {
        saveToHistory = false;
        mPager.setCurrentItem(pageHistory.pop().intValue());
        saveToHistory = true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a field to keep track of the index of the previous page using `mPager.getCurrentItem()` after each time the user navigates to a new fragment, then in the `onBackPressed()` method, you should be able to call `mPager.setCurrentItem(previousPage)`

Or, if the user can only page in order, then you don't need a field at all, and you could just do `mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem()-1)`

Comment: Users can navigate in either direction so the second solution won't work. I just tried implementing the first solution by adding an `OnPageChangeListener` and recording the indexes there but behavior was inconsistent. Sometimes the displayed page would not change even though I could see from the log that the next fragment was being instantiated.

Comment: Also, keeping track of the indices manually feels like a pretty 'un-android' solution given that the backstack already exists for this purpose

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why there's that inconsistency, but it is important to note that the ViewPager actually keeps 3 pages instantiated in memory at all times: the current page, the previous page, and the next page. Therefore, if you are currently on page 2 (pages 1, 2, and 3 are currently instantiated) and then move to page 3 for example, page 4 will be instantiated and page 1 will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I've made custom ViewPager and implement stack functionality in it.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    stack.push(getCurrentItem());
    super.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}

public int popFromBackStack(boolean smoothScroll) {
    if (stack.size()>0) {
        super.setCurrentItem(stack.pop(), smoothScroll);
        return getCurrentItem();
    } else return -1;
}
```