# 3 tabs with each one carry 1 fragment and when press back go to previous tab

Tags: android, tabs

I want to create 3 tabs and each one have single fragment,when i press back button in device instead of closing of app i need to go previous tab.I had try a lot but not find correct answer which is suitable for my app.I am new to development.

What i have in my project is 3 tabs when i am at tab 3 if i press it needs to go tab 2 instead of closing app.

What ever suggestions i get those are helped only go back to previous fragment.
**But i want go to previous tab when we press back button in android device.**

Comment: post code here what you have tried ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use backstack with ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712917/use-backstack-with-viewpager)

Comment: following is code which i used in my app.

Comment: i will try this and i will post my code my be you can get idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have different fragments in one tab if you press back button by using `OnBackPressed()` we can go for previous fragment.For that situation following code will help you.

```
    @Override 
public void On BackPressed(){
//You can check by write toast if it working are not.
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    // If there are back-stack entries, leave the FragmentActivity
    // implementation take care of them.
    //implement your code here.

    super.onBackPressed();
 }
}
```

It will help you to go back of your previous fragments not previous tabs.

this will help you understand.
[Separate Back Stack for each tab in Android using Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments])

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments] this will help you

Comment: that link is give lot of information edit your answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by overriding `onBackPressed()`.
The key here is to keep track of your current fragment and swatch tabs based on that info.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    switch(activeFragment){
        case 3: triggerTab2();
            break;
        case 2: triggerTab1();
           break;
        case 1: super.onBackPressed();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i had try this with my code but it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

**For creating Tabs with fragments Check this link -** 
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

For on Back button pressed you need to override `onBackPressed()` in the activity not in fragments. You need to handle back pressed and provide index of respective tab.

Hope it will help

Comment: i had try that but there is no back stack in that code.when i try to add it is not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // put switch or if which decide which fragment 
    Class fragmentClass = Fragment.class;
            Fragment fragment = null;
            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ((Activity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment).commit();

            // R.id.content_fragment => id of viewPager
}
```